# Nested ngFor displays only top level collection elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on nested ngFor loop to display list of elements with sub collections.

My goal is to create following structure

1. List item

   - item
   - item
   - item
2. List item

   - item
3. List item

   - item
   - item

the component code looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ProductCategoryService } from "../../services/product-category.service";
import { ProductCategory } from "../../models/productCategory.model";
import { ProductSubCategory } from "../../models/productSubCategory.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'category-info',
  templateUrl: './category-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-info.component.scss']
})

export class CategoryInfoComponent implements OnInit {

   categories: ProductCategory[];
   subcategories: ProductSubCategory[];

   collection: CategoryContainer[];

   constructor(private categoryService: ProductCategoryService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.categories = this.categoryService.CategoryList;
      this.subcategories = this.categoryService.SubCategoryList;

      this.collection = this.categories.map(x =>
          new CategoryContainer(x.name, this.getSubCategories(x.id)));

     console.log(this.collection);
   }

   getSubCategories(id) {
      return this.subcategories.filter(x => x.productCategoryId == id)
        .map(x=> new CategoryContainer(x.name, null));
   }
 }

 export class CategoryContainer {
    constructor(name: string, subs: CategoryContainer[]) {
      this.name = name;
      this.subs = subs;
     }

    public name: string;
    public subs: CategoryContainer[];

}
```

My HTML looks like

```
<div>
  <div class="row control-box">
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of categories; let i = index">
         {{i}} {{item.name}} 
       <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let sub of item.subs; let i2 = index">

             {{i2}} {{sub.name}}
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The component code generates correct data with sub elements.

Unfortunately at the binding it reports all the nested collections are undefined elements and on the screen i can see only following

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does this.collection contains after ngOnInit?

Comment: it contains proper elements with sub collections

Comment: I think the data might me wrong, because when I tested your html with mock data, it is working fine.

Comment: shouldn't you be using collection  instead of categories  in the view?

Comment: IMO there is a typo here, you should be using `*ngFor="let item of collection;` rather than `*ngFor="let item of categories;`

Comment: Stupid me,, thanks a lot, now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo here, you should be using `*ngFor="let item of collection;` rather than 
`*ngFor="let item of categories;`

P.S. posting the answer here, just for the sake of answered question. :)